# The equality operator seems to not work on chars

Tags: c++

I need to check if a string is a palindrome. I tried using the code below, but it appears that the `if`'s condition is always `false`, even when `line[i]` and `line[line.size() - i - 1]` are obviously not the same.
(`line` is a string, `palindrome` is bool):

```
for (size_t i = 0;i * 2 < line.size(); ++i){
    cout << line[i] << " == " << line[line.size() - i - 1] << endl;
    if (not line[i] == line[line.size() - i - 1]){
        palindrome = false;
        cout << "False" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of this code's output (I set `line` to `"helloworld"`):

```
h == d
e == l
l == r
l == o
o == w
```

Comment: `not` has higher priority than `==`. GCC and Clang warn about this (not MSVC though).

Comment: Use `!=` instead (it avoids to add extra parentheses)

Comment: This is one of the complications that you get with double negatives. Remove the `not` and change `==` to `!=`; far less confusing.

Comment: Thanks to rules of operator precedence, `not line[i] == line[line.size() - i - 1]` is equivalent to `(not line[i]) == line[line.size() - i - 1]`, and not to `not (line[i] == line[line.size() - i - 1])`.    Take note of the additional `()` I've inserted.

Comment: **Unrelated:** It is not an issue here but in general, prefer `a < b/2` instead of `a*2 < b`, because the former is not sensible to overflows. (But it's not an issue for such small values :) )

Comment: Thanks for help everybody, this ansers my question

Comment: @Fareanor In this case not an issue, but both of those expressions can yield different results. E.g. for `a=1; b=3;` the results of the expressions are `false` and `true` respectively.

Comment: @Peter Your comment should be an answer.